# setTimeout isn't reached by page.open in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to call `nextpage` function from the `page.open` in my script, but when I run this I get no output in `console` and no errors. I have debugged about it since a long time now, but haven't got any solution. The code is below:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/jannunzi/about';

page.open(url, function (status) {

    setTimeout(function(){
        nextpage();
        console.log("inside timeout.....");
    },5000);

    phantom.exit();
});

function nextpage(){
    console.log("huzefa...........................");
}
```

Here, none of the both console messages gets printed in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could it when you *immediately* exit PhantomJS (`phantom.exit();`)? JavaScript's `setTimeout()` is asynchronous, so statements that come afterwards are evaluated before the callback is called. You should move the exit into the callback for `setTimeout()`.

Comment: thnx , saved my life :)

Comment: And I didn't even have to study medicine for that. What an accomplishment :P